# Android: How to fetch large String Array from strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, java-native-interface

I have a script that fetches a large string array (with 100+ elements and each string having 500+ characters on an average). It used to work earlier. But as I went on adding more and more elements to the string array, the app started crashing and I came across this error:

```
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: chars == null && char_count > 0
 06-29 00:17:45.146 11930-12225/com.shahabas.planetofhorrors A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to NewString
```

This happens whenever I try to fetch the string array from *strings.xml*.

Here is the complete error log: https://gist.github.com/ShahabasShakeer/237b072dff8ee0ca2cb346241f66c005

The app crashes whenever I fetch large string array.
So is there a method to access string arrays with large number of elements from *strings.xml* without causing any crash or error?